# Swift - Compare colors at CGPoint

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, pixel

I have 2 pictures which I want to compare, if pixel color is the same to save it.
I detect the color of the pixel by this `UIImage` extension function:

```
func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> ??? {

    let pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.CGImage))
    let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

    let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

    let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

    return ???
}
```

For example, I run the scanner on picture 1 and save it in an array? Or dictionary? And after that I run the scanner on picture 2 and when I have the information from 2 pictures to compare it with what function?

I want to see on which CGPoint the pixels colors are identical from 2 images?

UPDATE:
I update getPixelColor to return me "(pos)(r)(g)(b)(a)" and after that I created this function which left only duplicates (BEFORE USING THIS FUNCTION YOU HAVE TO .sort() THE ARRAY!)

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    var duplicates: [Element] {
        var arr:[Element] = []
        var start = 0
        var start2 = 1
        for _ in 0...self.count{
            if(start2<self.count){
                if(self[start] == self[start2]){
                    if(arr.contains(self[start])==false){
                        arr.append(self[start])
                    }
                }
                start+=1
                start2+=1
            }
        }
        return arr
    }
}
```

This returns me something like this:
"(609.0, 47.0)1.01.01.01.0" I know that the color is black at this point I do x-536 to fit iPhone 5 screen and when I make an attempt to draw it again it draws something wrong... maybe I can't do it properly.. help?

Comment: return a `UIColor`, and check if they are equals? Note that difference between colors is a discussed topic with a lots of differents approach.

Comment: also - are you checking every single pixel? If you're scanning these pictures in, I don't think you have much chance of getting them lined up pixel-perfect, even before you start worrying about scanning each colour correct to 1/255 in each dimension.

Comment: UIColor is not conform to protocol hashable...
Some of the pixels are 100% identical, I want to see on which CGPoint are identical...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have the UIImage extension return a UIColor. use this method to compare each pixel of the two images. if both pixels match, add the color to an array of arrays.

```
extension UIImage {
    func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

        let pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.CGImage))
        let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

        let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}


func findMatchingPixels(aImage: UIImage, _ bImage: UIImage) -> [[UIColor?]] {
    guard aImage.size == bImage.size else { fatalError("images must be the same size") }

    var matchingColors: [[UIColor?]] = []
    for y in 0..<Int(aImage.size.height) {
        var currentRow = [UIColor?]()
        for x in 0..<Int(aImage.size.width) {
            let aColor = aImage.getPixelColor(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            let colorsMatch = bImage.getPixelColor(CGPoint(x: x, y: y)) == aColor
            currentRow.append(colorsMatch ? aColor : nil)
        }
        matchingColors.append(currentRow)
    }
    return matchingColors
}
```

used like this:

```
let matchingPixels = findMatchingPixels(UIImage(named: "imageA.png")!, UIImage(named: "imageB.png")!)
if let colorForOrigin = matchingPixels[0][0] {
   print("the images have the same color, it is: \(colorForOrigin)")
} else {
   print("the images do not have the same color at (0,0)")
}
```

for simplicity i made `findMatchingPixels()` require the images be the same size, but it wouldn't take much to allow different sized images.

**UPDATE**

if you want ONLY the pixels that match, i'd return a tuple like this:

```
func findMatchingPixels(aImage: UIImage, _ bImage: UIImage) -> [(CGPoint, UIColor)] {
    guard aImage.size == bImage.size else { fatalError("images must be the same size") }

    var matchingColors = [(CGPoint, UIColor)]()
    for y in 0..<Int(aImage.size.height) {
        for x in 0..<Int(aImage.size.width) {
            let aColor = aImage.getPixelColor(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            guard bImage.getPixelColor(CGPoint(x: x, y: y)) == aColor else { continue }

            matchingColors.append((CGPoint(x: x, y: y), aColor))
        }
    }
    return matchingColors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a different approach?

The Core Image filter `CIDifferenceBlendMode` will return an all black image if passed two identical images and an image with areas of non black where two images differ. Pass that into a `CIAreaMaximum` which will return a 1x1 image containing the maximum pixel: if the maximum value is 0, you know you have two identical images, if the maximum is greater than zero, the two images are different.

Given two `CIImage` instances, `imageA` and `imageB`, here's the code:

```
let ciContext = CIContext()

let difference = imageA
    .imageByApplyingFilter("CIDifferenceBlendMode",
        withInputParameters: [
            kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: imageB])
    .imageByApplyingFilter("CIAreaMaximum",
        withInputParameters: [
            kCIInputExtentKey: CIVector(CGRect: imageA.extent)])

let totalBytes = 4
let bitmap = calloc(totalBytes, sizeof(UInt8))

ciContext.render(difference,
    toBitmap: bitmap,
    rowBytes: totalBytes,
    bounds: difference.extent,
    format: kCIFormatRGBA8,
    colorSpace: nil)

let rgba = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(
    start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bitmap),
    count: totalBytes)

let red = rgba[0]
let green = rgba[1]
let blue = rgba[2]
```

If `red`, `green` or `blue` are not zero, you know the images are different!

Comment: Some of the pixels are 100% identical, I want to see on which CGPoint are identical...

Comment: Ah, OK, I misunderstood "I have 2 pictures which I want to compare, if pixel color is the same to save it.". I thought you wanted to save an image only if the two pictures were identical.